# C# cannot draw with creategraphics() under panel tool

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

i cannot draw lines with graphicspath over the panel tool. Where are panel - line is not visible.

Here is code in MainForm:

```
        private void MainForm_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        this.Controls.Add(panel1);
        g.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Gray);
        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
        gp.AddLine(330, 676, 330 + (c / 6), 676);
        gp.AddLine(330 + (c / 6), 676, 330 + (c / 6), 676 - (d / 3));
        gp.CloseFigure();
        g.FillPath(Brushes.Orange, gp);
        g.DrawPath(Pens.Black, gp);
        gp.Dispose();

    }
```

And MainForm.Designer

```
        // panel1
        this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        this.panel1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.MainForm_Paint);
```

Any suggestions what can be done to show drawn figures over panel?

Comment: You shouldn't even try! - __Never__ use `control.CreateGraphics`! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter. - The system needs to draw all the controls' surfaces at times you can't control; therefore all you want to add to those surfaces must be created from the one event that the system will call, which is the `Paint` event. Only __non-persistent__ graphics operation like displaying a dynamic rubber-band rectangle are ok with a `Graphics` object you get from `control.CreateGraphics()`.

Comment: Also: __All graphics sit on top of the control__ you draw on. But __all Controls sit on top  of their container__. - So, no this is not possible. You need to rethink your approach.

Comment: `Graphics g = e.Graphics();`  Remove that silly `this.Controls.Add(panel1);` line.  You don't add controls in a paint event.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, i will rethink my approach.